# Select all iframes and check them with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

My code is here:-

```
<iframe src="http://www.website.com/abc.ext" width="600px" height="400px"></iframe><br />
<iframe src="http://www.anotherwebsite.com/link.py" width="600px" height="400px"></iframe>
```

Now, I want to select both iframes with javascript and check their src. I want to allow only www.website.com for iframe. I want to build a javascript code what will show only the iframes containing www.website.com and others will be hidden.

Please let me know is it possible?

Comment: why not just delete the other iframes from "your code"?

Comment: Use `document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")`, then loop through that collection, get each `src` property, then check for the string in it: `if (item.src.indexOf("http://www.website.com") === 0)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var frames = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
for (var i in frames)
    if (!frames[i].src.match(/^http:\/\/www\.website\.com/))
        document.body.removeChild(frames[i]);
```

Something like this. You can replace the condition and do what you want as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery:

```
$('iframe:not([src*="www.website.com"])').hide();
```